# Why do I have to call operator<< as a method for SFINAE to work with void_t?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, sfinae, enable-if

I am trying to define a `has_ostream_operator<T>` SFINAE test for checking whether I can cout a given type. I have it working, but only if in my definition of `has_ostream_operator` I call `operator<<` as a method rather than as an infix operator. In other words this works:

`decltype(std::declval<std::ostream>().operator<<(std::declval<T>()))>`

This does not:

`decltype(std::declval<std::ostream>() << std::declval<T>())>`

Test case below (can also see at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d257d9d6e0f3f6d9). Note that I included a definition of void_t since I'm only on C++14.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace std {

    template<class...>
    using void_t = void;

}

template<class, class = std::void_t<>>
    struct has_ostream_operator : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct has_ostream_operator<
    T,
    std::void_t<
        decltype(
            std::declval<std::ostream>().operator<<(std::declval<T>()))>>
    : std::true_type {};

struct Foo {};

template<class X>
    void print(
        const X& x,
        std::enable_if_t<has_ostream_operator<X>::value>* = 0)
{
    std::cout << x;
}

template<class X>
    void print(
        const X&,
        std::enable_if_t<!has_ostream_operator<X>::value>* = 0)
{
    std::cout << "(no ostream operator<< implementation)";
}

int main()
{
    print(3); // works fine
    print(Foo()); // this errors when using infix operator version
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That definition of `void_t` induces undefined behavior ([namespace.std]/1).

Comment: Are you sure you want to go through all this trouble to convert an otherwise compile-time error to a runtime error? I'm very curious about the actual use-case. Is your goal really to be able to write `print(x)` for any `x` and have that runtime message show up whenever `x` turned out not to be printable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm assuming your "infix" version used this expression:

```
std::declval<std::ostream>() << std::declval<T>()
```

The reason that matches for `Foo` is because the first part, `declval<ostream>()` produces an rvalue of type `ostream&&`. This matches a non-member [`operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2):

```
template< class CharT, class Traits, class T >
basic_ostream< CharT, Traits >& operator<<( basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&& os, 
                                            const T& value );
```

That overload simply forwards the call along:

> Calls the appropriate insertion operator, given an rvalue reference to an output stream object (equivalent to `os << value`).

You should instead check for that directly. All the overloads take an `ostream` by *lvalue* reference, so you should test that too:

```
std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<T>()
```

Answer (score 6):

You need

```
std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<T>()
//                       ^
```

`std::declval<std::ostream>()` is an rvalue; you are hitting the catch-all `operator<<` overload for rvalue streams.

Comment: Would you consider the fact that there is such a catch-all a standard defect (a la `std::function` originally being constructible with anything)?

Comment: @Barry I suspect that it wasn't really a problem before `void_t`, but nowadays....might be worth an LWG issue.

Comment: First there was C++11, Then there was C++void_t. Soon there will be C++is_detected.

Answer (score 4):

If you use infix notation, the rvalue stream inserter is found, since `declval` returns rvalues per se; [ostream.rvalue]:

```
template <class charT, class traits, class T>
basic_ostream<charT, traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<charT, traits>&& os, const T& x);
```

This overload currently accepts all arguments for `x`. I've submitted LWG [**#2534**](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2534), which, if resolved accordingly, will make your initial code work as expected.

A temporary workaround is to make `declval` return an lvalue reference, i.e.  adjust the template argument to one:

```
std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<T>()
```